# How can I translate words with a python script?

Tags: python

So we have to translate numbers from English to German. I feel I am doing it all wrong because I get no
output when I test my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

english = sys.stdin.read().split()

num = {}

with open("translation.txt") as f:
    data = f.read().split("\n")

i = 0
while len(data[i]) < 0:
    n = data[i].split()

    n1 = n[0]
    n2 = n[1]
    if n1 not in num:
        num[n1] = n2
    i = i + 1

i = 0
while i < len(english):
    n = english[i]
    if n in num:
        print(num[n])
    i = i + 1
```

Please help. Am I even getting the code to open the text file? the text file contains numbers translated from English to German

Example of translation.txt

```
one: eins
two: zwei
three: drei
four: vier
five: funf
six: sechs
seven: sieben
eight: acht
nine: neun
ten: zehn
```

Comment: Can you give an example of `translation.txt` and `stdin` ?

Comment: Why is it `len(data[i]) < 0`? I think the big other is that you're not getting rid of the colons.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code had some major logical errors. First of all, a comparison was wrong for the loops. You also split the line but you left `:` in the keys. Also checking if the word already exists is not necessary, but I left it as you wrote. I also added two side translation just in case you will need it.

Here is my implementation of the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

english = sys.stdin.read().split()

num = {}

with open("translation.txt") as f:
    data = f.read().split("\n")

i = 0
while i < len(data):
    n = data[i].split()
    print(n)
    n1 = n[0].replace(':', '')
    n2 = n[1]
    if n1 not in num and n2 not in num:
        num[n1] = n2
        num[n2] = n1
    i = i + 1

print(num['one'])
print(num['eins'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You read inputs from standard input via `sys.stdin.read()`. This requires reading ALL characters until an EOF is met, which would happen only if:

1. An EOF is entered via the keyboard (Ctrl-D for Unix-based systems and Ctrl-Z for Windows);
2. The input is redirected from another stream that ends with an EOF, such as a file stream.

If the input is entered line by line via the keyboard, the output won't be seen until an EOF is seen. If it is desired that the output is shown immediately after one line of input, `input()` should be used instead of `sys.stdin.read()`.

Other issues have been explained in @Raguel's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have a major issue with application logic, as were mentioned in previous answers:

- First of all, we need to load dictionary - our resource to operate.
- Second, we can start the translation, for example word-by-word from continues user input

The compact solution (require python 3.8):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

with open("translation.txt", "r") as f:
    dictionary = { k: v.strip()  for k, v in [line.split(":") for line in f.readlines()]}

while word:=input("Word to translate: "):
    try:
        print(dictionary[word])
    except KeyError:
        print(f"No translation found for the word: {word}")
```